# Running an application made for the E71 on the E72

Tags: java-me, nokia, lwuit

I have an application that runs on the Nokia E71 phone. My questions are:

1. Can this application run on a Nokia E72 phone without any changes being made to the jad and jar?
2. If not, what changes would I need to make to the target platforms etc. (on Eclipse) to make it run on the desired phone?

P.S: I am running the application with LWUIT.
Please let me know in case any more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change the code for Nokia E72. Because both are Symbian S60 3rd Edition and both are having same resolutions. One main different is Nokia E71 having Feature Pack 1 based on Symbian OS v9.2 and Nokia E72 having Feature Pack 2 based on Symbian OS v9.3.  If you are testing the application means [download](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html) separately for both platforms. But AFAIK its not affected your application. Look below technical specification for both,

[Nokia E71 specifications](http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/nokia-e71/specifications)

[Nokia E72 specifications](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/devices/nokia-e72/specifications)